# XML/XSLT attribute output

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm working on a little XML/XSLT project and I'm having trouble retrieving more than one element from the XML file.

I want to retrieve the client name(Attribute) and the transaction amount(Attribute) but it doesn't work. The only element attribute I can output is client `name`.

I've tried to change `<xsl:template match="client">` to `<xsl:template match="list">` but then everything was showing and I don't want the question element to print.

Once names and amounts will output, I need to sum the amounts to show the total but first I really need to get the amounts to output. Any idea?

XML File :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="xslt.xml" 
type="application/xml"?>
<list> 
<client name="Morton"> 
<transaction amount="43" />
<question>Who?</question>
<transaction amount="21" /> 
</client> 
<client name="Mingus"> 
<transaction amount="6" /> 
<transaction amount="32" /> 
<question>Where?</question>
<transaction amount="45" /> 
</client> 
</list>
```

XSLT File :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="client">
<html>
<body>

<p>Name:</p>
<xsl:apply-templates select="client" />
<xsl:value-of select="client" />
<xsl:value-of select="@name" />

<p>Total:</p>
<xsl:value-of select="transaction" />
<xsl:value-of select="@amount" />

</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Current Output Result:

```
Client:
Morton
Total:
Client:
Mingus
Total:
```

Desired Output Result:

```
Client: Morton
Total: 64
Client: Mingus
Total: 83
```

Comment: Can you add an example of your desired output?

Comment: Of course, it's in there now! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're having is with your xpaths. Your context is `client` so all paths have to be relative to that. So if you're trying to get the `amount` attribute of a child `transaction`, the xpath would be `transaction/@amount`.

However, if you use `<xsl:value-of select="transaction/@amount"/>` and there are more than one `transaction` children, you'll only get the value of the first occurrence. (In XSLT 1.0 anyway. In XSLT 2.0 you'll get all of the values concatenated together.)

Here's how I would do this:

**XML Input**

```
<list> 
    <client name="Morton"> 
        <transaction amount="43" />
        <question>Who?</question>
        <transaction amount="21" /> 
    </client> 
    <client name="Mingus"> 
        <transaction amount="6" /> 
        <transaction amount="32" /> 
        <question>Where?</question>
        <transaction amount="45" /> 
    </client> 
</list>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="html"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/list">
        <html>
            <head></head>
            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="client"/>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="client">
        <p>Client: <xsl:value-of select="@name"/></p>
        <p>Total: <xsl:value-of select="sum(transaction/@amount)"/></p>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**HTML Output**

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
   </head>
   <body>
      <p>Client: Morton</p>
      <p>Total: 64</p>
      <p>Client: Mingus</p>
      <p>Total: 83</p>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot or clearing that up! I can see now why it wasn't working and I appreciate it! :)